# Why is touch failing?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I must be missing something obvious.

This works:

```
[root@host2 /]# cd /home/mysite/public_html/../logs 
[root@host2 /home/mysite/logs]# touch x
```

Why doesn't this?

```
[root@host2 /]# touch /home/mysite/public_html/../logs/x
touch: cannot touch `/home/mysite/public_html/../logs/x': No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's a good chance that one of the directories in `/home/mysite/public_html/../logs/` is actually a symbolic link.  The `cd` command built into most modern shells does a little magic in this case, so that `cd ..` takes you to the "logical" parent directory -- which takes into account how you got there.

When you try to `touch /home/mysite/public_html/../logs/x`, you don't get this magic.

Consider:

```
$ ls -l /home/lars
public_html -> /var/www/lars
logs/
```

If I `cd /home/lars/public_html` I'm actually inside of `/var/www/lars`.  So technically, `../logs` does not exist (because the `logs` directory I want is actually in `/home/lars`, not in `/var/www`, which is the "real" parent of `/var/www/lars`.

Comment: Well, that's correct, and how stupid :-) Links should work all over the place. Now I guess I'm going to have to get my script to CD into the directly and then do the touch... annoying. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`public_html` is a symlink to somewhere completely different.  As a shell, `bash` tracks symlinks in paths differently than many other programs do.  Try this: `cd /home/mysite/public_html` then run `pwd` (the bash command) and `/bin/pwd` (the program).  When `touch` tries to use the path, it will go to `/var/www/sites/mysite/` or wherever that link points, then go up a directory from there to get to `logs/`... only to fail to find `/var/www/sites/logs/`.